# What is Equilibrium Equivalent Concentration (EEC)?

Tags: radiation

Recently I am doing a research about radon measurement. During the process I met two concepts named [Equilibrium Equivalent Concentration](http://www.google.com/search?q=Equilibrium+equivalent+concentration) (EEC) and [Potential Alpha Energy Concentration](http://www.google.com/search?q=Potential+Alpha+Energy+Concentration) (PAEC), but until now I am not so clear about the definition of EEC, who know this clearly? Could you be nice to tell me exact definition of Equilibrium equivalent concentration? and what is the different between EEC and PAEC?

Answer (score 1):

Equilibrium equivalent concentration means, that what you measure is one thing, but the end result is defined as EEC what means you say, that what you measure and calculate afterwards is equivalent to a theoretical gas-air mixture, that is in equilibrium for the 238-U and its's daughter elements (like Radon-222).
This is because you cannot measure all the daugters of the decay line, just some of them, but the radiological hazard is calculated with all of the daugters in the decay line, so this is a necessary aproximation.

I cannot tell you anything from PAEC actually, but I know this much from radon EEC.

Answer (score 1):

PAEC for an arbitrary mixture of short-lived radon daughter products:

$$ c_P = \sum_j c_j \varepsilon_{p,j}\lambda^{-1}_j \;\;\; [\frac{\text{MeV}}{\text{m}^3}] $$

where $c_j \; [\frac{\text{Bq}}{\text{m}^3}]$ is the activity concentration of the radio Nuclids Po-218, Pb-214 and Bi-214 and $\varepsilon_{p,j}\lambda^{-1}_j \; [\frac{\text{MeV}}{\text{Bq}}]$ is the alpha energy concentration divided by the activity of the daughter product $j$.